# Why Isn't This L-System Code Returning a String?

Tags: python, string, l-systems

I'm trying to write a program that takes a string and replaces certain characters with other strings. (A->AB) and (B->A) in this case. When I run it I expect the final string to be returned but instead nothing is returned.

```
def createSystem(seed,depth):

    startString = seed
    endString = ""

    for i in range(depth): 
        endString = processString(startString)
        startString = endString
    return endString   


def processString(oldstr):
    newstr=""
    for char in oldstr:
        newstr=newstr+applyrules(oldstr)

    return(newstr)

def applyrules(oldstr):
    output=""

    for char in oldstr:
        if char=="A":
            output.join("AB")
        elif char=="B":
            output.join("A")

    return(output)


print(createSystem("AB",1))
```

In this example I would expect the seed "AB" to produce the string "ABA", however nothing is returned to the console. Why is this? Thanks in Advance! - Eli

EDIT: The program compiles and doesn't produce any errors.

Comment: @Andreas While it's important for new programmers to learn basic debugging techniques, I don't think it will help here; the way the code is written suggests to me some misconceptions about how various things actually work.

Comment: As an aside, the code *does* produce a string - just an empty one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you expect, for example,

```
output = ""
output.join("AB")
```

to mean: "`output` is an empty string; now cause `output` to become the result of adding `'AB'` to the end of the existing `output`".

It does not.

It means: "`output` is an empty string; now make a new string by putting the existing `output` in between each character of `'AB'`, and throw that new string away (don't give it a name)."

In Python, strings are *immutable* - nothing you do with them can change their contents in-place, like with a list. You must use an operation that creates a new string, and *reassign the result*. Also, the `join` method is used to take an entire *sequence of* strings, and join them together, for example:

```
' '.join(['a', 'b', 'c']) # produces 'a b c'
```

The code doesn't raise an error because a Python string is also a valid sequence of strings (each one consisting of a single character). This is a special behaviour of strings, not shared by other sequences.

To use that method here, you would need to produce the sequence of `'AB'` and `'A'` fragments, and just call `''.join` (i.e., we put an empty string in between each fragment) with that to get the result directly. We can do this with a [*generator expression*](https://dbader.org/blog/python-generator-expressions). It looks like this:

```
def process_string(oldstr):
    return ''.join(
        'AB' if char == 'A' else 'A'
        for char in oldstr
    )
```

(Notice the naming convention for the function - see [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for standard style conventions in Python)

That's really all you need. *Or* you could apply the += logic that you had in mind in the original code, to build up the string a piece at a time (this [is less efficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter's_algorithm)):

```
def process_string(oldstr):
    newstr = ''
    for char in oldstr:
        newstr += 'AB' if char == 'A' else 'A'
    return newstr # parentheses are meaningless here.
```

*Or* you can use the built-in support for this kind of string translation already provided by the string class (but this is more awkward than it ought to be):

```
def process_string(oldstr):
    return oldstr.translate(str.maketrans({'A': 'AB', 'B': 'A'}))
```

Here, `str.maketrans` calls a class method that belongs to the string class (named `str` and available automatically as a global from startup). You can read about these methods in the language documentation: [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate); [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans).

It appears that you got confused and tried to do both things. Kudos for trying to put the logic for the transformation rule into a separate function (`applyrules`), but that function would need to return *just the fragment corresponding to a single input character*. (After all, you've already set up to iterate over characters, and designed `applyrules` to accept a single character at a time.) The work that it does is simple enough that - at least for now - a separate function isn't really necessary (unless it helps you understand the code).

In the above examples, I have used a [*ternary conditional operator*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator) to represent the logic of choosing the replacement fragment for each input character. This is necessary for the generator expression approach, because you are writing a single *expression* and have nowhere to put an `if:`/`else:` block.

Comment: As a side note, it's perfectly safe to just keep reusing the same single name to re-assign the result of each step in `createSystem`, instead of shuffling things around between two separate names. You can even just use the input parameter name (`seed`).